# How to make every line in a bubble like chat conversations?

Tags: typography, text-decorations

I've had a plain chat conversation and need display them similarly to how they are designed in Messenger. Since this is a long conversation, I need a method to do it at once. I know this might be impossible to have all, so I just need to mimic it as close as possible.

- Left-aligned gray bubbles (103, 184, 104) with black text;
  Right-aligned green bubbles (241, 240, 240) with white text
- Bubbles are only split after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.
- Left and right edges are half circle
- Margins between same color bubbles are small, margins between different color bubbles are large.

[image]

<sup>FYI: [What word processing tools that can work with complicate text boxing?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/102442/26474) in Graphic Design

[How to wrap every paragraph with a custom text box in Word?](https://superuser.com/q/1275141/301042) in Super User</sup>

Comment: have a look on tcolobox package https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: @Bobyandbob I don't know what else I should add

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With `tcolorbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\bubblewidth}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\bubblewidth}{.75\textwidth}}
\definecolor{bubblegreen}{RGB}{103,184,104}
\definecolor{bubblegray}{RGB}{241,240,240}

\newcommand{\bubble}[4]{%
  \tcbox[
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    #2,
  ]{\color{#3}\begin{varwidth}{\bubblewidth}#4\end{varwidth}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl

\NewEnviron{rightbubbles}
 {
  \raggedleft\sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{rounded~corners}{white}{\BODY}
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=southeast}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}\par
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=east}{white}{##1}\par
     }
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=northeast}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}\par
   }
 }
\NewEnviron{leftbubbles}
 {
  \raggedright\sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblegray}{rounded~corners}{black}{\BODY}
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=southwest}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}\par
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=west}{black}{##1}\par
     }
    \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=northwest}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}\par
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{rightbubbles}
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.

Left and right edges are round.
\end{rightbubbles}

\begin{leftbubbles}
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.

Left and right edges are round.
\end{leftbubbles}

\begin{rightbubbles}
Single
\end{rightbubbles}

\begin{leftbubbles}
End
\end{leftbubbles}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change the definition of `\bubble` to

```
\newcommand{\bubble}[4]{%
  \tcbox[
    arc=5mm,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    #2,
  ]{\color{#3}\begin{varwidth}{\bubblewidth}#4\end{varwidth}}%
}
```

then the output is as follows:

[image]

### Improved version

You can define the spacing between bubbles by setting `\bubblesep`. Different color bubbles are enclosed in `flushleft` and `flushright` environments, so there will be `\topsep` space between them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newlength{\bubblesep}
\newlength{\bubblewidth}
\setlength{\bubblesep}{2pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\bubblewidth}{.75\textwidth}}
\definecolor{bubblegreen}{RGB}{103,184,104}
\definecolor{bubblegray}{RGB}{241,240,240}

\newcommand{\bubble}[4]{%
  \tcbox[
    on line,
    arc=4.5mm,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    #2,
  ]{\color{#3}\begin{varwidth}{\bubblewidth}#4\end{varwidth}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl

\NewEnviron{rightbubbles}
 {
  \begin{flushright}
  \sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{rounded~corners}{white}{\BODY}\par
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=southeast}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}
    \par\nointerlineskip
    \addvspace{\bubblesep}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=east}{white}{##1}
      \par\nointerlineskip
      \addvspace{\bubblesep}
     }
    \bubble{bubblegreen}{sharp~corners=northeast}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}
    \par
   }
   \end{flushright}
 }
\NewEnviron{leftbubbles}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}
  \sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblegray}{rounded~corners}{black}{\BODY}\par
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=southwest}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}
    \par\nointerlineskip
    \addvspace{\bubblesep}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=west}{black}{##1}
      \par\nointerlineskip
      \addvspace{\bubblesep}
     }
    \bubble{bubblegray}{sharp~corners=northwest}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}\par
   }
  \end{flushleft}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{rightbubbles}
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.

Left and right edges are round.
\end{rightbubbles}

\begin{leftbubbles}
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.

Left and right edges are round.
\end{leftbubbles}

\begin{rightbubbles}
Single
\end{rightbubbles}

\begin{leftbubbles}
End
\end{leftbubbles}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Seems like there's no way to make the edges rounder, right? And why do you decide to use `__ooker_bubbles_` string? It's nice to have my name, but isn't it long?

Comment: It's an expl3 convention that functions an variables should have a common prefix and a name. For the rounder edges I added an example.

Comment: Thanks. If we use `arc=4.5mm` the edges will be more natural. One more step: can the space between the same color bubbles be smaller? Another step: can the space between two different color bubble be larger?

Comment: I want to use `\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}` for normal text but it affects the bubble space. Do you know how to prevent this?

Comment: did you mean `\color{#3}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` in `\newcommand{\bubble}`? It doesn't work for me

Comment: @Ooker Sorry, it should be added at the beginning of both `leftbubbles` and `rightbubbles`. Place it just after `\begin{flushright}` or `\begin{flushleft}`

Comment: `{\color{#3}\begin{varwidth}{\bubblewidth}#4\end{varwidth}}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}` works. Is there any potential harm for this, or for what you just suggest?

Comment: @Ooker No, that's wrong.

Comment: but it just... works?

Comment: Yes, but for the wrong reason. The right place is where I suggested.

Answer (score 16):

In plain TeX (using pdfTeX) we can do this:

```
\font\ssf=cmssdc10
\def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 g}}
\def\Blue{\pdfliteral{0 0 1 rg}}
\def\White{\pdfliteral{1 g}}

\def\bptopt#1{.9963 0 0 .9963 0 0 cm 17 0 0 #117 0 3.5 cm }
\def\circle{.5 0 m .5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c
           -.5 -.276 -.276 -.5 0 -.5 c .276 -.5 .5 -.276 .5 0 c }
\def\hcircle{.5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c }
\def\fullround{\pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ \circle f Q}}
\def\halfround{%
   \ifnum\count255=13
      \pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ -.5 -.5 m .5 -.5 l .5 0 l \hcircle  h f Q}%
   \else \ifnum\count255=14
      \pdfliteral{q \bptopt- -.5 -.5 m .5 -.5 l .5 0 l \hcircle  h f Q}%
   \else
      \pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ -.5 -.5 m -.5 .5 l .5 .5 l .5 -.5 l h f Q}%
   \fi\fi
}
\def\xround#1#2{\if #1#2\halfround \else \fullround\fi}

\def\messenger#1#2{\medskip\setbox0=\vbox{\penalty13
   \widowpenalty=14 \clubpenalty=0 \interlinepenalty=0
   \def\\{\unskip\break}\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil\parindent=0pt \ssf #2\par
   \setbox1=\box2
   \loop \setbox1=\lastbox
       \unless\ifvoid1
          \unskip\unskip \count255=\lastpenalty \unpenalty
          \setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip}
          \setbox1=\hbox to\hsize{\hss\Blue\xround l#1%
              \rlap{\vrule height12pt depth5pt width\wd1 \xround r#1}\White 
              \box1 \Black \if l#1\hfill\fi}
          \global\setbox2=\vbox{\box1 \vskip1pt \unvbox2}
   \repeat
   }
   \unvbox2
   \medskip
}


\hsize=9cm

This is test:

\messenger r {
This is the native format from messenger \\
Notice, how the borders of the sides are circular, not straight and the last
notice is here.
}
\messenger l {
Second message \\
is here.
}

\bye
```

Edit: I modified the code in order to enable to print two variants: left aligned, if `\messenger l` is used and right aligned, if `\messenger r` is used. As your comment says.

The result:

[image: messenger2]

**Edit** The specifications from OP were changed after my first result was published here. First, the colour was blue and bubbles were right aligned. Second, bubbles must be left aligned too. The last change of the specification includes a new request for colours and for formatting the paragraphs. I supposed that when there is my code published then slight changes of formatting a paragraphs or changing colours is just simple task for OP. But probably it cannot be expected because OP does not know what does mean `\bye` for example. Moreover, egreg presented second solution here based on a specific Expl3 language. He was in advantage because he knew newest specification from OP. I cannot keep only Expl3 solution here, because it is obscure language from my point of view which cannot help to teach the basics TeX principles. So, there is my second solution using TeX primitives and accepting the new specification form OP. I hope that there will be no more specification changes from OP.

```
\font\ssf=cmssdc10
\def\Black{\pdfliteral{0 g}}
\def\Blue{\pdfliteral{0 0 1 rg}}
\def\White{\pdfliteral{1 g}}
\def\Gray{\pdfliteral{.945 .941 .941 rg}}
\def\Green{\pdfliteral{.404 .722 .408 rg}}
\def\bcolor#1{\if r#1\Green \else \Gray \fi}
\def\fcolor#1{\if r#1\White \else \Black \fi}

\def\bptopt#1{.9963 0 0 .9963 0 0 cm 17 0 0 #117 0 3.5 cm }
\def\circle{.5 0 m .5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c
           -.5 -.276 -.276 -.5 0 -.5 c .276 -.5 .5 -.276 .5 0 c }
\def\hcircle{.5 .276 .276 .5 0 .5 c -.276 .5 -.5 .276 -.5 0 c }
\def\fullround{\pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ \circle f Q}}
\def\halfround{%
   \ifcase\count255
       \pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ -.5 -.5 m -.5 .5 l .5 .5 l .5 -.5 l h f Q}%
   \or \pdfliteral{q \bptopt+ -.5 -.5 m .5 -.5 l .5 0 l \hcircle  h f Q}%
   \or \pdfliteral{q \bptopt- -.5 -.5 m .5 -.5 l .5 0 l \hcircle  h f Q}%
   \or \fullround \fi
}
\def\xround#1#2{\ifdim\ht1>12pt
   \dimen0=\ht1 \advance\dimen0 by-12pt
   \hbox to0pt{\hss\vbox{\xroundA#1#2\kern\dimen0 \xroundA#1#2}%
      \rlap{\kern-8.5pt\raise4.5pt\vbox{\hrule width17pt height\dimen0}}\hss}% 
   \else \xroundA#1#2\fi}
\def\xroundA#1#2{\if #1#2\halfround \else \fullround\fi}

\long\def\messenger#1#2{\medskip\setbox0=\vbox{\penalty13
   \widowpenalty=0 \clubpenalty=0 \interlinepenalty=0
   \everypar={\setbox0=\lastbox\endgraf\vbox\bgroup
      \everypar={\vrule height12pt width0pt}}
   \def\par{\ifhmode\endgraf\egroup\fi}
   \def\\{\unskip\break}\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil\parindent=0pt \ssf #2\par
   \everypar={}\let\par=\endgraf \setbox1=\box2
   \loop \setbox1=\lastbox
       \unless\ifvoid1
          \unskip\unskip 
          \count255=\ifvoid2 \ifnum\lastpenalty=13 3\else 2\fi 
                    \else    \ifnum\lastpenalty=13 1\else 0\fi \fi
          \unpenalty
          \ifdim\ht1>12pt \else
             \setbox0=\vbox{\unvbox1 \lastbox \setbox1=\lastbox 
                      \global\setbox1=\hbox{\unhbox1\unskip\unskip}}
          \fi
          \setbox1=\hbox to\hsize{\hss\bcolor#1\xround l#1%
              \rlap{\vrule height\ht1 depth5pt width\wd1 \xround r#1}%
              \fcolor#1\box1 \Black \if l#1\hfill\fi}
          \global\setbox2=\vbox{\box1 \vskip2pt \unvbox2}
   \repeat
   }
   \unvbox2
   \medskip
}

\hsize=9cm

This is test:

\messenger r {
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.

Left and right edges are round.
}
\messenger l {
Left-aligned gray bubbles (241, 240, 240) with black text

Right-aligned green bubbles (103, 184,104) with white text

Bubbles only break after a paragraph (equivalent to an enter press 
when chatting). Long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble.
}
\messenger r {
Single
}
\messenger l {
End
}

\bye
```

[image: messenger3]

Comment: I've update my question. Can you make different color for different bubbles, and long message with multiple lines will be kept in one bubble? Thanks

Comment: also, what does `\bye` do? I actually have to delete it to run the script

Comment: `\bye` is defined in plain TeX. I mentioned that this was tested in plain TeX in my answer. I don't use LaTeX. If you are using LaTeX then you must remove `\bye` (of course) and you must add tons of another lines of code and you must pray that it will work.

Comment: I am *very* happy to see you around, Petr! `:)`

Comment: you are using e-TeX's `\unless`? that's a bit modernistic ;-)

Comment: @jfbu The `\pdfliteral` seems to be modernistic too. On the other hand, LaTeX kernel seems to be a bit ancient from my point of view. ;-)

Comment: It's also nice that (the first version of) this solution is _half_ the length of the (first) `expl3` one - but neither is particularly easy to understand :)

Comment: Of course, both languages are a bit obscure. If neither of them is particularly easy to understand for you then I strongly recommend to start with study of TeX primitives -- native TeX language, no Epl3. Because without knowledge of principles of TeX you are unable to do nothing with TeX. And Expl3 cannot help you with such understanding.

Comment: Putting Expl3 aside for a while, why don't you use XeTex or ConTeXt?