# How to stop `^^` getting converted to `M`?

Tags: compiling, verbatim

`\^^`,`\^\^`,`\^ \^` all give error. `\verb|^^|` works, but if put inside `\begin{leftbubbles}` and `\end{leftbubbles}` from this answer [How to make every line in a bubble like chat conversations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405189/50146) it gives error

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
```

The same is true for rightbubbles. As you might have guessed, the `^^` are the emoji ^^

Why is `^^` compiled as `M`, and how to prevent this?

Comment: Look up `^^` in the TeXbook index.

Comment: `\verb|^^|` perhaps but it depends why you want `^` at all, it is not a common character to need in a document

Comment: note `^^` does not get converted to M, but it does read the following one or two characters and adjust the character code. You presumably are following `^^` by a linebreak which is control-m so `^^-linebreak` is M

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It doesn't work if put inside `\begin{leftbubbles}` and `\end{leftbubbles}` from this answer [How to make every line in a bubble like chat conversations?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405189/50146). The error is `! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }`.  The same is true for rightbubbles. As you might have guessed, the `^^` are the emoji ^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle can you elaborate your last sentence?

Comment: If you can't use `\verb` try `\texttt{\string^\string^}` or `\texttt{\textasciicircum\textasciicircum}`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot this works. You can make it as an answer

Comment: Time to repost link to my [favourite rant](https://adityam.github.io/context-blog/post/lower-learning-curve/). FWIW, in ConTeXt `^` has catcode letter outside of math mode, so typing `^^` gives you two carets in output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you type `^^` (under normal category code setting, that is, when `^` has category code 7), TeX looks for the next character, say it has ASCII code *x* (less than 128) and substitutes the whole construction with the character having ASCII code *x* − 64 or *x* + 64, depending on which one is in the range 0–127.

Exception: if the following character is among `0123456789abcdef`, TeX will look for a further character and, if again among those, it will substitute the four characters with the one having the ASCII code as specified by interpreting the two characters as hexadecimal digits.

It follows that typing `^^` for getting two carets is not possible. Also `\verb` doesn't work in argument to other commands and, unfortunately, the contents of a `bubblesright` environment must be absorbed as an argument to a macro.

Solution: define a specific command for that emoticon.

I suggest to add the following just before `\ExplSyntaxOff`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ei}{m}{ \texttt { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } }
\NewDocumentCommand{\eihh}{}{ \texttt { \tl_to_str:N ^ \tl_to_str:N ^ } }
```

and then you can type

```
\begin{rightbubbles}
Here \ei{;-)}

What \eihh

Another \ei{:-D}
\end{rightbubbles}
```

[image]

### Alternative trickery.

Add, before `\ExplSyntaxOff`

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\ei}{m}{ \texttt { \tl_to_str:n { #1 } } }
\char_set_active_eq:nN { `^ } \c_math_superscript_token
\AtBeginDocument
 {
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `^ } { "8000 }
  \char_set_catcode_other:n { `^ }
 }
```

Then the input

```
\begin{rightbubbles}
Here \ei{;-)}

What \ei{^^}

Another \ei{:-D}
\end{rightbubbles}
```

will produce the same output as before.

Comment: in this context, using a specific command for emojis particularly might be wise, but in general I think it's simpler to use `\texttt{\string^\string^}`, isn't it? And even in this context, why should a specific command be needed over the quick hack?

Comment: @Ooker I added another trick, changing the category code of `^`

Comment: @Ooker A specific command can be changed in the preamble; tricky input must be searched for every occurrence.

Comment: Why not just use 5E, the hex code for `^`?  Second, I think you mean "three characters" not "four characters" in "[...]it will substitute the four characters with the one having the ASCII code[...]"

Comment: @Yakk Two carets and two hexadecimal digits

Comment: But what do you think about other options (`\texttt` or hex code)?

Comment: @Ooker I am defining `\eihh` exactly as `\textt{\string^\string\^}`