# one text block in tikz environment with two styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I'm trying to make a space of a given width, e.g. 10cm, in a tikzpicture environment where i can input text either with style-1 or style-2.  Style-1 is for example `[text width=6cm, align=left]` and style-2 is `[text width=6cm, align=right]`. As usually `\node` needs coordinates, i used 'chains', but I've not yet found how to set the width of the whole text block. I tried to nest a node with style-1 or style-2 within a `\node at (0,0) [text width=10]` but that doesn't work.

Here is an illustration done with a wysiwyg program.

[image]

here is my mwe:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[start chain=going below]{
\node [on chain, text width=6cm] {\lipsum[1][1]}; \\
\node [on chain, text width=6cm] {\lipsum[1][2]}; \\
\node [on chain, text width=6cm] {\lipsum[1][3]}; \\
\node [on chain, text width=6cm] {\lipsum[1][4]}; \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: here's my own solution, but i'm still expecting a better one

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[start chain=going below, node distance=.2cm]
  \node [on chain, align=left, text width=6cm] {\lipsum[1][1]};
  \node [on chain, align=right, text width=6cm, xshift=4cm] {\lipsum[1][2]};
  \node [on chain, align=left, text width=6cm, xshift=-4cm] {\lipsum[1][3-8]};
  \node [on chain, align=right, text width=6cm, xshift=4cm] {\lipsum[1][9]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `tcolorbox` for that. But you need to define two node styles, one for each chatter. And maybe using `chain` would be better thant a `matrix of nodes`.

Comment: There is also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266713/resemble-popular-messenger-with-latex-macros

Comment: But I was actually looking for https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/405132/how-to-make-every-line-in-a-bubble-like-chat-conversations

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624775/chat-bubbles-with-picture-and-name-attached